# Is there a way to mark an Objective-C method that does not return?

Tags: objective-c

In clang, you can mark a C function that does not return like this:

```
extern void go_die_somewhere( void ) __attribute__((noreturn));
```

Is there an equivalent attribute for Objective-C methods?

I've tried adding `__attribute__((noreturn))` to the method declaration every way I can think of, but the compiler ignores it. I also couldn't find any `NS_...` macro with the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try `+ (void) __attribute__((noreturn)) someMethod` as used [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/1.1.0/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m#L157).

Comment: I tried that already, and it's also ignored. (I thought this worked when I tried it again, and even up-voted the answer, but I had the wrong target selected.)